# Change encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization

I would like to change string encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 in Javascript. How can I do it?

I need it because I've designed a widget. User just copies < script > tag from my site and puts it on his. This script creates div and puts into div widget contents with text.

If target website is in UTF-8 encoding - it works fine. But when it is in ISO-8859-2 than text that is encoded in UTF-8 is displayed on site with ISO-8859-2 and as a result I see trash.

Comment: Yes, 8859-2, it's character table for my Polish language

Comment: ... What for? Both JavaScript and most browsers, can handle UTF-8 just fine.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the encoding for the strings that JavaScript is using itself, or the encoding for the whole web page?

Comment: I've updated question to explain 'what for' part.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone Only text. I consider that it is not possible to change encoding of a div that i create from my script

Comment: Convertion from UTF-8 (Unicode) to a code-page (like ISO-8859-x) is not always possible so you shouldn't try to do this, if you are using the UTF-8 all you have to do is to ask the user to assure that is website is using UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using e.g. "ĉ" in your JavaScript code, use Unicode escapes such as "\u0109".

Comment: and how to convert all diacritic characters from regular for to \u notation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the output, you can replace all special characters with unicode escapes (e.g. `\u00e4` for `ä`). The browser can interpret it correctly regardless of document encoding.

The easiest way to do this would be to put the string into a JSON encoder. Both PHP's and Ruby's does that. Don't know about other implementations though.

Another solution that might work is to add `charset="utf-8"` to the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just need to convert your wdiget from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 and provide 2 versions of script.