# How can I get non-english characters from ajax form to MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a form that submits data using the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).  From there it goes through some server side handling and finally stored in a MySQL db.

Upon submitting these characters `áâãäï` they become sent to the server as `Ã¡Ã¢Ã£Ã¤Ã¯'` (before hitting the database).  The same type of thing happens with Japanese characters, etc.

I have tried both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 for the form encoding, page encoding, php server side encoding and db encoding. Still no luck.

Comment: have you tried urlencoding the characters within javascript before they are submitted? `encodeURIComponent()` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, JavaScript works with UTF-16 strings, and functions such as `encodeURIComponent()` encode characters to UTF-8, so it is probably not the JavaScript code that is the problem. The problem is likely within your PHP code.

- Every page sent by the server (including the page the form is on) has to have the header `Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`. You can check this using Firebug's Net panel.
- Always [set the character encoding](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8/mysql) of your MySQL connection before making any queries. Otherwise, MySQL will interpret each byte of the UTF-8 string as a Latin-1 character, which can easily cause what you describe. Use code such as:

  ```
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");    // works in old versions of PHP (< 5.2)
  mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);    // works in PHP 5.2+
  ```
- Keep in mind that *some* (not all) PHP string functions will [mangle Unicode text](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8).

Comment: I narrowed it down to php's serialize function which was the culprit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The characters are probably being pasted in from WORD (ISO-8859-1). Ajax expects UTF-8 ONLY, so you'll have to convert them on the client before sending them to the server.

See: [Change encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117024/change-encoding-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-2-in-javascript)

Comment: The characters are as if added from a keyboard.  As for the link referenced I do not see a solution to the issue (other than the fact you recommended I 'convert' them before sending) can you elaborate?

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({ 
        scriptCharset: "utf-8" , 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});